# Actualize Database Data with Functions Cloud

Tags: javascript, android, database, typescript, function

I am developing an Android application and I have a problem that I cannot solve despite reading the tutorials on Inernet ...

In my application, the user has a life bar (100 points) and I would like that every 60 seconds (for example) the life bar decreases by a certain value (Even when the user is logged out).
The data is registered in a Firebase database:

```
{
    "actualize": {
        "state" : true,
        "time" : 60000
            },
    "users": {
        "-M-gSECRUGQMUrBbJ8wF": {
            "healthBar": 100,
            "substractionPoint" : 1
            },
        "-M-gSEijB-lClfuKkMUh": {
            "healthBar": 75,
            "substractionPoint" : 1.5
            }
        }
}
```

So I want to use the Functions Cloud part of Firebase, but I can't make a TypeScript code that suits me. Here is the diagram I would like:

```
//Data recovery from the database
actualiseState -> boolean
actualizeTime -> number

<idUser>/healthBar -> number
<idUser>/substractionPoint -> number

//A trigger ?
do {
<idUser>/healthBar = (<idUser>/healthBar) - <idUser>/substractionPoint

update value in database

sleep(actualizeTime)
}

while (state = true)
```

Thank you in advance for your help ;)  /  Translated by Google Translate

Comment: This does not look like TypeScript code. Are you working off some example?

Comment: How about if you save the time. Then you can calculate the life bar points afterwards